# What happens when one side of a cube is multiplied by 7?

Tags: geometry, volume, area

I have a question that seens obvious, but I know the answer can't be that simple.

**What happens to the volume and surface area when all sides of a cube is multiplied by 7?**

At first I assumed that both the surface area and volume would just be multiplied by 7, but I know that isn't the case. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Fixed question to be more clear.

Comment: If by "multiplying a side of a cube by $7$" you mean make all the side lengths of the cube $7$ times longer, then the surface area will be $7^2$ times larger and the volume will be $7^3$ times larger. You might just choose a cube and do the calculation, to see. You'll likely understand why, too

Comment: Are the other two dimensions left the same (so if you started with a unit cube you now have a $1 \times 1 \times 7$ brick) or are all three dimensions multiplied by $7$, keeping it a cube?

Comment: @mixedmath That's it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let the side of the cube be $a$.  Multiplying each dimension by $7$ gives a cube $7a \times 7a \times 7a$  The original volume was $a^3$ and the new volume is $(7a)^3$, so it gets multiplied by $7^3$. The surface area of the original cube is $6a^2$, so if you multiply the side by $7$ the area gets multiplied by ????

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiply all sides by 7. I've edited the question for clarity.